# What is the link between amnestic functor and amnesia?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, terminology, definition

A functor $F:\mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ is by definition **amnestic** if any isomorphism in $\mathcal A$ that is sent by $F$ to an identity is an identity itself.

I fail to see why the term "amnestic" is used for this labeling.

Can someone make me wiser?

Especially a good understanding of used terms is very helpful for my memory when it concerns mathematical concepts.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question was downvoted. IMV that is just absurd. A good understanding of terminology is very handsome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps there is some better reason I'm not aware of, but I've always assumed it was just in reference to "forgetful functors".  Most typical forgetful functors are amnestic, and it is a convenient property to require of functors you want to behave like the familiar forgetful functors in certain ways.  (And indeed, the only context in which I've ever seen amnestic functors used is in discussing an abstract theory of forgetful functors and similar concepts.)

Comment: Thank you. I am wiser now. Further let's wait some time and see if someone else can make us both even wiser. If not then your answer will be accepted.